# How to Run Jasmine testing framework 2.0 from command line for Node project

Tags: node.js, jasmine

Previously, I used the npm package node [jasmine-node](https://www.npmjs.org/package/jasmine-node). However, the documentation says it only supports Jasmine 1.3.1.

I'd like to run [Jasmine 2.0](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html) tests on a Node project.

I found [jasmine-core](https://www.npmjs.org/package/jasmine-core), which looks like it contains the Jasmine 2.0 libraries, but not the command line runner.

What do I need to do to make this work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Late response you may know the answer at this point but, try the `jasmine-node module 2.0 beta4`

Install it via following command

```
  sudo npm install -g jasmine-node@2.0.0-beta4
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

It's now installed without the -beta4 part of the version number

```
sudo npm install -g jasmine-node@2.0.0
```

Comment: Hiya, this may well solve the problem... but it'd be good if you could edit your answer and provide a little explanation about how and why it works :) Don't forget - there are heaps of newbies on Stack overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise - what's obvious to you might not be so to them.

Answer (score 2):

There is now a https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine-npm

It lacks several of the bells and whistles that `jasmine-node` has, but

- it uses the latest https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-core (`jasmine-node` uses jasmime 2.0 as of February 2015, while `jasmine-npm` uses jasmine 2.2).
- it comes from the jasmine maintainers themselves